# Backbone.js - make POST request without saving a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, model

I'm wondering is there a possibility to make `this.model.save(data, options)` in **Backbone** without writing data to model?

I have a server endpoint where I need to POST json `{ field1: 'bbb', field2: 'aaa' }` - server writes these fields into db like `list: [{ field1: 'bbb', field2: 'aaa' }]`.

The problem is that Backbone adds these fields to model as well. And I have model like `{ id: '111', field1: 'bbb', field2: 'aaa', list: [{ field1: 'bbb', field2: 'aaa' }] }` and that's wrong..

Is there a way to make save without writing send data to model? Or maybe simply use jquery `$.post` method and set model on success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to fix this would be to either change the data returned by the server, or override the parse method in your model and remove the extra attribute.

A second thought would be to give your moel a single attribute of list and set that with the data dict and have the server return the same. This won't be 100% compatible with general Backbone model usage though.

gotta go..

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define `sync` function and make ajax there
2. You can define `parse` function and write something like this

   parse:function(data)
   {
       return data.list;
   }

2 is the better approach. If setting some field will affect another one, server will return it and you will always have actual data in the model.